# Magento 1.7 - How to stop DB backup that was initiated through deleting a website?

Tags: mysql, database, magento, backup, magento-1.7

I have 61 websites on a live Magento instance. 10 or so are no longer used but we get about a thousand orders per week and have been running on Magento for over 2 years.

I went to delete one of the websites in the Manage Stores, and there is a little drop down for creating a DB backup that I left set to yes, thinking originally that it meant backup the reference in the DB at first glance.

It has been about an hour now and our sites are virtually down as no one can place orders, and the admin is unaccessible.

Is there a safe way to stop this process?

Is there a way to at least trace progress to see if there is some sort of SQL lock? I do not want to wait for hours only to find out that it will never finish. Ive read around here that the built in Magento backup tools are not good at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?